# Recommended Way to get Proper Linting for Flow in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, flowtype

I've read lots of discussions on here about how to setup VSCode to allow linting of Javascript files when `// @flow` is enabled at the top of the file.

I believe I've implemented things properly but am still getting mysterious errors that seem to indicate otherwise.

For example, I'm getting a `Missing type annotation for destructuring.Flow(InferError)` for `classes` here:

```
const AddCustomer = ({ classes }) => {
```

So I changed it to this:

```
const AddCustomer = ({ classes:any }) => {
```

but the error persisted.

Here is another observation of the way things are working in my VSCode at the moment:

```
export const useFetch = (initialUrl, initialData) => {
```

With this code I get warnings that the two parameters are not typed.  So I changed the code to this:

```
export const useFetch = (initialUrl:string, initialData:any) => {
```

Nothing happened immediately but when I saved the file then the warnings went away.  Not a biggie but that's not the way I expect linters to work.

Might anyone have any thoughts on why `@flow` linting is not quite working correctly in my VSCode?

Comment: What Flow extension are you using?

Comment: This one: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=flowtype.flow-for-vscode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, for the first issue regarding `Missing type annotation for destructuring.Flow(InferError)`, I believe the type is placed in the wrong place. The syntax `({ classes: any })` is renaming the `classes` property on the first parameter to `any`. A more thorough explanation can be read in MDN's page [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Nested_object_and_array_destructuring). To correctly specify the type of the object parameter, you will want to place the type definition after the object

```
const addCustomer = ({ classes }: { classes: any }) => { ... };
```

This may feel verbose and repetitive, but the idea is to separate the code from the types. For example, the type definition of a customer may be imported from another file, so the code would look more like

```
// types.js
export type Customer = { classes: any };

// index.js
import type { Customer } from './types';

const addCustomer = ({ classes }: Customer) => { ... };
```

This allows the parameter to be specified in any way (e.g., without destructuring) and the type to be specified in any way.

For your second issue, check to make sure that the setting `flow.runOnEdit` is set to `true`. This will allow Flow to check your files without saving. If that does not seem to fix the problem, then I would raise an issue with the maintainers of the VSCode extension.

Comment: Thanks for this!  Your `({ classes }: { classes: any })` cleared up the linting error.

As for `flow.runOnEdit`, it was indeed set but I unchecked it and rechecked it just to be sure.  Anyhow, not the end of the world that I have to save the files to display linting issues.